# php error-log on UserFrosting after loading main page

Tags: php, error-handling, userfrosting

I'm trying to install UserFrosting
and i get these errors after loading  the main page

```
[01-Oct-2016 18:28:29 Asia/Jerusalem] PHP 6. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() C:\Server\userfrosting\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:301
[01-Oct-2016 18:28:29 Asia/Jerusalem] PHP 5. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() C:\Server\userfrosting\initialize.php:25 
[01-Oct-2016 18:28:29 Asia/Jerusalem] PHP 4. spl_autoload_call() C:\Server\userfrosting\initialize.php:25 
[01-Oct-2016 18:28:29 Asia/Jerusalem] PHP 3. UserFrosting\UserFrosting->setupGuestEnvironment() C:\Server\userfrosting\initialize.php:193 
[01-Oct-2016 18:28:29 Asia/Jerusalem] PHP 2. require_once() C:\Server\index.php:10 
[01-Oct-2016 18:28:29 Asia/Jerusalem] PHP 1. {main}() C:\Server\index.php:0 
[01-Oct-2016 18:28:29 Asia/Jerusalem] PHP Stack trace: 
[01-Oct-2016 18:28:29 Asia/Jerusalem] PHP Strict standards: Declaration of UserFrosting\User::fresh() should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::fresh(array $with = Array) in C:\Server\userfrosting\models\database\User.php on line 570
```

and i can't find the problem
thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `PHP Strict standards: Declaration of UserFrosting\User::fresh() should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::fresh(array $with = Array) in C:\Server\userfrosting\models\database\User.php on line 570` means that the `UserFrosting\User::fresh()` method should accept the same types of arguments as `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::fresh(array $with = Array)`.

The issue can be reproduced with the following code:

*test.php*

```
<?php
class A {
  public function test ($arg = 'default value') {
    echo $arg;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public function test () {
    echo __METHOD__;
  }
}

$b = new B;
$b->test();
```

Running the script:

```
$ php test.php
PHP Warning:  Declaration of B::test() should be compatible with A::test($arg = 'default va...') in /home/ruslan/tmp/src/test.php on line 12
```

To fix it we should just modify `test` method in the derived class *according to the parent* method:

```php
class B extends A {
  public function test ($arg = 'X value') {
    echo __METHOD__;
  }
}
```

Running the script:

```
$ php test.php 
B::test
```